# Java/SWT - Want to detect the Drop area in a SWT DnD operation

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt, rcp

Hi Stackoverflow people !

I'm implementing a Java RCP plugin for a project management tool, using SWT and close to a MVC logic.

I need to do a kind of **chronologic timeline** in which milestones (some kind of deadline event in project management) can be drag and dropped.

I realized  it using several SWT labels (basically, an array of 36 labels in a horizontal line, 3 per month of the year).

Here is a screenshot of the actual GUI:

[image]

The user will have to drag a milestone from the drag label (the (X) on the left), and drop it on the desired label/part of the month. Then, for now the only effect it has is to set the text field of the drop target label to (X).

I created 2 "Model" classes : a class Milestone (that will later be improved with others elements, such as informations about what has to be done at this date regarding of the project for example) and a class Square (square has to be linked with the drop labels). 
The Square class features :

- boolean isEmpty ( check if the label or square already has a milestone on it )
- int nbMilestone ( number of milestone on a label/square )
- int id ( the number of the label or square from 0 to 35 )

The Milestone class features :

- year ( gets the current year )
- positionId ( on which label or square the milestone has been dropped )

What I want is when a user drags and drops a milestone on a label, it updates the Milestone and the Square class, at least with the position information. I have difficulties to get the information **On which label did the user drop the milestone ?**.

The 36 labels are created in a `for(;;)` loop, with some drag and drop listeners inside this loop.

---

**EDIT #2 :** here is my actual code :

```
    // Drag source label in order to create milestones by a Drag'n'Drop
    // operation
    final Label milestone_drag_label = new Label(compA, SWT.NONE);
    milestone_drag_label.setText("(X)");
    milestone_drag_label.setData("milestone", milestone);

    // Setting up the Drag Listener for the milestone label
    DragSource ds_ms_label = new DragSource(milestone_drag_label,
            DND.DROP_MOVE);
    ds_ms_label.setTransfer(new Transfer[] { TextTransfer.getInstance() });
    ds_ms_label.addDragListener(new DragSourceAdapter() {
        public void dragSetData(DragSourceEvent event) {
            // event.data = milestone_drag_label.getText();
            event.data = (Milestone) event.widget.getData("milestone");
            from_ms_label = true;
        }
    });

    // Display configuration for the labels (3 labels per months, so they're
    // called
    // third, as third of a month)
    GridData gd_third = new GridData();
    gd_third.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    gd_third.widthHint = 15;

    for (w = 0; w < 36; w++) {

        final Label third = new Label(compA, SWT.BORDER);
        third.setLayoutData(gd_third);
        board[w] = third;
        square[w] = new Square();
        square[w].setId(w);

        third.setData("square", square);

        DropTarget dt = new DropTarget(board[w], DND.DROP_MOVE);
        // DropTarget dt = new DropTarget(third, DND.DROP_MOVE);
        dt.setTransfer(new Transfer[] { TextTransfer.getInstance() });
        dt.addDropListener(new DropTargetAdapter() {
            public void drop(DropTargetEvent event) {
                if (event.data == null) {
                    event.detail = DND.DROP_NONE;
                } else {
                    // third.setText((String) event.data);
                    Milestone milestone = (Milestone) event.data;
                    Square square = event.widget.getData("square");
                    milestone.setPositionId(square.getId());
                    printMilestone(milestone);
                }
            }
        });
```

The `printMilestone()` method in the end just writes the attributes year and positionId in a .txt file.

I got an error at the line : `Square square = event.widget.getData("square");`

so I added a cast : `Square square = (Square) event.widget.getData("square");`

But when I run my RichClient app, I got this error :

> org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Data does not have correct format for
>   type

Comment: What do you mean with 'addModifier on the label text field'? Each possible drop target is represented by a `Label` widget, right? Or do you use `Text` widgets?

Comment: Yes I use 36 labels as drop targets (all in a line). Declared this way : Label[] board = new Label[36]; Then in the drawView() method I instanciate those 36 labels using a for(;;) loop, creating each time a drag and a drop listener. I want to link these labels to my Square and Milestone beans. 
In other words, how can get the information about know on which label a milestone has been dropped ?

Comment: third.setData("square", square); should be third.setData("square", square[w]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand: the user should be able to drag a *milestone* label that serves as a drag source and drop it over one of the 36 *non-milestone* labels which serve soley as drop targets. As a result a model element that is associated to the drop-target label should be updated.

All of the *milestone* labels should have a drag-listener, no need for a drop-listener as they never serve as drop-targets.
All of the 36 labels should have assigned a drop-listener, they don't serve as a drag source, hence there is no need for a drag-listener. 
To see how the basic drag-and-drop functionality works, I think [this snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet78.java) will help.

To associate the labels with their respective model elements, you can either use a `Map` or use `setData()`

The code to create the *milestone* label would look like this:

```
Labe label = new Label( ... );
label.setData( "milesone", milestone );
label.addDragListener ( new DragSourceListener () {
  @Override
  public void dragSetData( DragSourceEvent event ) {
    event.data = ( Milestone )event.widget.getData( "milestone" );
  }
  @Override
  public void dragFinished( DragSourceEvent event ) {
    // mark the milestone label as 'assigned' if desired
  }
} );
```

The code for each *square* label would look like this:

```
Label label = new Label( ... );
label.setData( "square", square );
label.addDropListener ( new DropTargetAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void drop( DropTargetEvent event ) {
    if( event.data == null ) {
      event.detail = DND.DROP_NONE;
    } else {
      Milestone milestone = ( Milestone )event.data;
      Square square = event.widget.getData( "square" );
      milestone.setPositionId( square.getId() ); // or whatever it takes to update the model
      // update label text if necessary
    }
  }
```

The above snippets use `setData()` to associate model elements and widgets, the same would also work with `Map`s.

There are also [more DnD snippets](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/) an [article](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-DND/DND-in-SWT.html) and an excellent [DnD Example](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/examples.php) that lets you follow the DnD mechanics for all widgets in great detail and experiment with different settings.

Comment: I edited my first message, I have to admit it wasn't clear enough !

Comment: After re-reading the updated question, I amended my answer in details, but the general approach should work. Where exactly does the answer not fit?

Comment: Actually yes you are right, your answer was good enough ! But there's still something that doesn't work, it appears that it's not possible to add a drop listener to a label. The only method available is addDragDetectListener, but I'd rather prefer to add a listener for a drop operation, which should be more safe.

Comment: I added a short edit with the code snippets you gratefully wrote, if you have any idea about the error I got it would also be much appreciated.